# A better word to indicate slowness/high latency?

Tags: terminology

We are comparing two techniques in computer science.
We want to say X has **"significantly high latency"** when executed on system Y.

Is there a better one-word term we can use for the above to mean the same as 'significantly high latency'?
e.g., slow <-- but a better word than slow?

Comment: High latency isn't equivalent to slow. It may mean delayed reaction, but in computing usually high latency solutions will deal with bulk data and be overall faster than low-latency solutions that just don't provide the throughput.

Comment: I would say that "high" on its own means it is significant. Otherwise the system just has latency, so "high latency" or "significant latency."

Comment: Although this has already been migrated once, I think it would be answered better on the [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) stack. This is because it requires a technical term rather than general English.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I agree. In particular, when you want an alternative name for existing technical terminology, I think looking for new names is not a good place to start. The first thing to do is determine why you want an alternative name, and whether the costs of introducing a new name are worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question ("*... has .?. when executed ...*") is phrased so as to seek a noun.

*latency* is about delay (for many possible reasons). "*High latency*" implies longer delays. "*significantly high latency*" is not so simple to understand because significance depends on application and context. The addition of "*significantly*" therefore adds undefined meaning to "*high latency*", perhaps the loose suggestion that the delay is especially or unusually high, or that the delay somehow matters a lot.

This makes it difficult to find one word that expresses adequately the reasonably tight meaning of *high latency* while retaining the connection with an undefined context.

One candidate is:

> retardation = the process of making something happen or develop slower than it should
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retardation)

By this definition, retardation acts as a single word for *high latency* while also referring obliquely (using"... than it should") to a contextual expectation that it should have been lower.

"*X has/shows retardation when executed on system Y*"

Nevertheless, it seems risky to introduce a new word to try to replace a conventionally used term (or a short phrase derived from it) merely for the sake of one-word brevity.